# Non admin users not able to lock and Edit Items which are getting generated by Data Provider

Tags: data-provider

There is a Data Provider implemented in the solution which is creating items in my Sitecore solution from an SQL server database. The implementation was done by someone else so I am not too sure what exactly how it is implemented.

The items created by this data provider are editable using the Admin users but not by any non admin users. When editing these items using non admin users, the "lock and edit" link does not do anything.

The lock and edit functionality works fine for items that are not coming from data provider

Is there any configuration in Data Providers that can restrict non admin users from editing an item?

Sitecore version: 9.3 vanilla

Comment: I'm closing this because it will need conversation to diagnose. Without more details on what the data provider is and what it is doing it will be very hard to guess at the answer

Answer (score 2):

It is difficult to say what is wrong without understanding how items are created. But this definitely looks related to access rights.

You start by comparing 2 item -

- 1st is created from Data Provider
- 2nd is the one created by content author that behaves as expected.

Then you can check it's `Security` field (*Standard field*). I suspect, you will find a difference here.

[image]

Then you will need to check your implementation that is setting this Security.

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned the items are created by a data provider. I guess this will be using the Data Exchange Framework. So if you see all the items in your data provider, there will be a step that will be created using the "Iterate data and run pipelines" template.

I guess here you can find something about the items that are being created. Also, if in your implementation, there will be any custom pipeline set for this, you can check the code and it will help you to identify the root cause of this.

You can find out about this using this Sitecore document.

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/def/20/data-exchange-framework/the-iterate-data-and-run-pipelines-pipeline-step.html

I also wrote a blog to share some information about the data exchange framework, that you can refer to for more help.

https://sbhatiablogs.wordpress.com/2019/11/21/a-simple-data-exchange-framework-setup/

Hope this helps.